# How to debug "Debug Assertion Failed. Buffer too small"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, buffer, assertion

When I'm using `strcpy_s` always appear the same error, `Debug Assertion failed. L Buffer is too small &&0`. Can someone help me to solve it? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.
[image: error message]

```
struct Nod{
    char *Number;
    char *Name;
    Nod *drt, *stg;
};



void Insert(Nod *&p, char* n, char nr [])
{
    if(p==0 )
        p=makeNod(n, nr);
    else
    {
        ...
    }   
}

Nod * makeNod(char *name, char nr[])
{
    Nod *p=new Nod;
    p->Name=new char [strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy_s(p->Name, strlen(name), name);  //Assertion failed          
    strcpy_s(p->Number, strlen(nr), nr);
    p->stg=p->drt=0;
    return p;  
}
int main()
{

    Nod *p=0;
    int c;
    char nr[9];
    char*name=new char [20];
    cin >> c;
    while(c!=0)
    {
        cout << "Name:  "<< endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Number:  "<< endl;
        cin >> nr;
        Insert(p, name, nr);
        cin >> c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `strcpy_s()` seems to be the size of the *buffer* pointed to be the first argument. Since the string copy will need to copy `strlen(name)` characters *and* a terminating null character you'll need to provide a buffer which is *at least* one character bigger than `strlen(name)`. In fact, you *did* allocate a buffer of the appropriate size! You just didn't inform `strcpy_s()` about that fact.

Also, once you get over this error you'll find that you haven't allocated any memory for `Number`. I'd also recommend to actually safe the result of `strlen(str)` as the operation *may* be expensive, e.g., when the string is really long.

Answer (score 0):

First, `strcpy_s` in debug mode has checked that the length specified (`strlen(name`) is not enough to fit the `name` + the terminating `\0`, so it asserts.

Second, you did not reserve a buffer for `p->Number`.

```
    Nod *p=new Nod;
    p->Name=new char [strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy_s(p->Name, strlen(name)+1, name); // <-- +1, to not miss the null character at the end
    p->Number=new char [strlen(nr)+1];      // <-- You missed this
    strcpy_s(p->Number, strlen(nr)+1, nr);
```

Finally, use `std::string` and save yourself these headaches.